# Error when compiling source code with Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Using OpenCV 2.4.10 (same case with 2.3.1)
I got this trouble when compling my project in Visual Studio 2012 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core2410d.lib'
I added PATH Variables; on Visual Studio, I done Additionnal Include Directories; and Input Linker is :

```
opencv_core2410d.lib
opencv_imgproc2410d.lib
opencv_highgui2410d.lib
opencv_ml2410d.lib
opencv_video2410d.lib
opencv_features2d2410d.lib
```

and else Libraries Please help (My code was just to test if OpenCV works with VS1012)

Screens:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mySR.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmykc.jpg]

Comment: BTW, Get the vc9 lib folder out of your Visual Studio 2010 paths. Remember it is not safe to mix and match versions of Visual Studio or mix and match Debug and Release.

Comment: Also in your explorer you are showing x64 libraries but using Visual Studio 2010 to generate a 32 bit application in the other screen capture. Good thing you are correctly using the x86 libraries in that screen capture.

Answer (score 3):

You don't add the paths to additional include directories (that's where it looks for headers), but under `"Additional Library Directories"`, under the linker section of the project properties.

Comment: I did !! two libs: ****/opencv/build/include/lib & ****/opencv/build/include

Comment: @BiLLiXx are the files actually there? Is the error that it can't find them? If so, the path is probably misspelled or you didn't fill in the correct section.

Comment: Of course files already exists !! everything is okay, but <I got this error ! dunnow why !! I tried 2012 & 2010 Visual Studio, with 2.4.10 & 2.3.1 & even 1.0.0 opencv 
HEEEELP >_<

Comment: @BiLLiXx Shouting and exclamation marks won't help. First, calm down. Second, understand that visual studio works this way - you tell it the directories to look in and what files to look for. It's unlikely it's a bug with the IDE. Can you post 2 screenshots - one with the files in the directory, one with your project settings and additional include directories?

Comment: @BiLLiXx it looks like you didn't read my answer. Under Linker there's **another section** "additional library directories". **Not** "additional include directories" under "C/C++"...

Comment: It's empty, what should I put ? Libraries directories (on the photo)?

Comment: Now, there's another erreor
LINK: fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF file: invalid or corrupted file

Comment: @BiLLiXx that's a different issue, post another question. ;)

Comment: Lol, ok; tnx a lot :)